How to implement a wallet button using web3.js v2
I have been using sveltekit + @solana/wallet-adapter-base, @solana/wallet-adapter-phantom to build my solana frontend dapp, this is not good because they depends on web3.js v1 which depends on bs58 which depends on node:buffer which would cause my cloudflare pages app crash.
I want to find a svelte library that use web3.js v2, but I find nothing, a related app is https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/example/ but written in react, I'm not very familiar with react.
So I'm here to ask if someone can guide me to write a wallet button using @solana/web3.js v2 from scratch, best to use sveltekit or pure js.
I made a simple demo by myself at https://github.com/xcaptain/solana-wallet-demo
Here are some questions puzzles me when I was developing this demo.

What's the register, unregister events used, do I have to listen them in my app?
How to check if a UiWallet is connected, this is important when recover a WalletAccount from local storage.
Is it possible to put @wallet-standard/app, @wallet-standard/features, @wallet-standard/ui, @wallet-standard/ui-registry, @solana/wallet-standard-features into  a single package to reduce peer dependency?
Dependencies of @solana/wallet-standard-features seems to be outdated, should depends on ^0.0.0-20240703212708

